# Center a popup but getting error while dragging it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup

I have a problem with my popup. I want to center it so I use following CSS code

```
#wrap-all {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:999;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.wrap-pop {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

The popup now is at the center. But when I click on the title of my popup in order to move it, the popup will jump to the left and top. I think because of the transform CSS command, but if I remove transform CSS command, the popup will not be at the center anymore.

My HTML like this

```
<div id="wrap-all">
    <div class="wrap-pop">
        <div class="layerTop">
            <strong>The title is here</strong>
            <a href="#" class="layerClose"><img src="../images/close.png" alt="close layer" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="layerCon">  
            <p>The first line</p>
            <p>The second line</p>
            <p>The third line</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function layerOpen(url){                
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'GET',
        url     : url,
        success    : function(data){
            $('.content-pop').html(data);
            $('.wrap-pop').draggable({handle:".layerTop"});
        }
    });     
}
```

Please help me to solve it. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What's your html/javascript look like? Put that here, as well.

Comment: Like @Araymer said, edit your post with some HTML and Javascript and we will be able to help you.

Comment: I just added my HTML, JavaScript and CSS as well. Please help me